# Error, query failed to create a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new in php, and I'm follow a tutorial to access a MySql Server. I installed the xampp in my desktop, so my web server is localhost. I have two files, "config.php" responsible for the binding configuration and "opendb.php" responsible for connecting to MySql server.

When I run the file initdb.php in my browser, I receive this message:

```
Error, query failed: CREATE TABLE students( id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT, fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id) )
```

and don't know why don't creates the table.

This is my file initdb.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$queryFile = 'students.sql';
$queries = implode('', file($queryFile));

$arr = split(';', $queries);
array_pop($arr);

foreach ($arr as $query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed: '.$query);
}

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

And this is the file students.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE students(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO students (fname, lname) VALUES('Harry', 'Potter');
INSERT INTO students (fname, lname) VALUES('Ron', 'Wesley');
INSERT INTO students (fname, lname) VALUES('Hermione', 'Granger');
INSERT INTO students (fname, lname) VALUES('Chidori', 'Kaname');
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you able to create the table form command prompt. Also, I think it should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`, example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm).

Comment: I modified to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and continues to show the same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
```

With

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: I modified my line and continues to show the same message

Comment: Forget I had modified the wrong document. It's works now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`, [example here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm)